# Problems with axios, Spring boot and base64

Tags: java, spring-boot, react-native, base64, axios

I am trying to do a post from my react native app to my Spring Boot application but I'm getting this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character a

React Native Code:

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'myip',
    data: {
      teste: photo.image.base64,
    },
    headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'},
  }) 
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log("works");
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Spring Boot Code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Map<String, String> upload (@RequestBody Map<String, String> payload) {
    byte[] imageByte;
    String encodedString = payload.get("teste");
    String fileName = (new Date()).toString();
    fileName = fileName.replace(' ', '_');
    fileName = fileName.replace(':', '_');

    try {
        imageByte = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedString.toString());
        FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File(fileName + ".png"), imageByte);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("error");
    }
    return response;
}
```

Edit:
Stacktrace -

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character a
        at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Unknown Source)
        at com.pac.upload.UploadController.login(UploadController.java:33)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
```

I cannot see what I'm missing. Anyone could help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show stack trace ?

Comment: Eugen, I edited the post with the stacktrace

Comment: exception is under method `at com.pac.upload.UploadController.login(UploadController.java:33)`
. How does the text under `photo.image.base64` looks like ?

Comment: you can check here if you text is correct: https://www.base64decode.org/

Comment: Try adding a `consumes` parameter to your `@RequestMapping` annotation and indicate that this is `application/json`, matching the request.  (Otherwise, if Spring can't automatically figure out the content negotiation it will fall-back to the default for POST which is base64 encoded key-value pairs.) see https://www.journaldev.com/3358/spring-requestmapping-requestparam-pathvariable-example

Comment: Sofend, this is not needed because @RequestBody annotation.

Comment: Yes, it's correct Eugen. I don't know if the problem is with axios or Spring boot yet.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my example about upload image from react with Axios.

**Server:**

```
@PostMapping("/{businessId}/gallery")
    public Object singleImageUpload(@RequestParam("newImage") MultipartFile file) {
        if (file.isEmpty()) {
            return new GeneralResponse(ErrorsEnum.INVALID_IMAGE);
        }
        try {
            Business business = getUserBusinessLogged();
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();

            ...

            return new GeneralResponse(ErrorsEnum.OK);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error saving file", e);
            return new GeneralResponse(ErrorsEnum.SAVE_FAILED, "Problems saving file.");
        } catch (ControlledException ex) {
            return new GeneralResponse(ErrorsEnum.SAVE_FAILED, ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**Axios Client:**

```
const postGalleryImageRequest = async (sessionToken, businessId, image) => {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('newImage', image);
    const result = await api.post('business/' + businessId + '/gallery', data, {
        headers: { 
            Authorization: sessionToken,
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        }
    })  .then((response) => {
            return response.data
        })
        .catch(error => {
             ....
        })
    return result;
}
```

**Axios setup:**

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const baseUrl = 'https://host:port/api/';

export default
   axios.create({
      baseURL: baseUrl,
      timeout: 30000
   });
```